# Is "I'm done" a correct way of saying this?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is "I'm done" a correct way of saying that you have finished your education phase? Or should it be said in another way? Thank you

Comment: What "education phase" do you mean?

Comment: "I'm done" alone is more akin to "I quit" rather than "I've now left school & gone on to higher education". We need more detail to answer this.